# How can I use LINQ to filter and sort rows from one collection to another?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Default { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Default { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Also this which returns ICollection

```
var menu = _menuRepository.GetPk(pk);
```

Can someone show me how I can use LINQ to:

```
a) Get the data from menu
b) Select only rows where Status = "00"
c) Order by Order
d) Put the data into the MenuItem class
```

I heard there are maybe two ways of coding this. Can anyone explain these and advise which would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var menuItems = _menuRepository.GetPk(pk)
    .Where(m => m.Status == "00")
    .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
    .Select(m => new MenuItem 
                 { 
                     Order = m.Order,
                     Title = m.Title,
                     Type = m.Type,
                     Default = m.Default,
                     Link = m.Link 
                 });
```

You can throw `.ToList()` at the end to materialize collection immediately.

Answer (score 6):

Jimmy's answer looks right to me - here's the equivalent in query expression form:

```
 var query = from m in _menuRepoistory.GetPk(pk)
             where m.Status == ""
             order by m.Order
             select new MenuItem
             {
                 Order = m.Order, Title = m.Title, Type = m.Type,
                 Default = m.Default, Link = m.Link
             };
```

You might want to consider adding a `MenuItem` constructor which takes a `Menu`, or a `ToMenuItem` method to `Menu`, so you could just use:

```
 var query = from m in _menuRepoistory.GetPk(pk)
             where m.Status == ""
             order by m.Order
             select m.ToMenuItem();
```

(As with Jimmy's answer, you can call `ToList` to materialize the results in a `List<T>`.)

Comment: Or create an extension method to do that :)

Comment: @jessehouwing: I wouldn't do that - it looks too specific to merit an extension method, really.

Comment: Agreed, though I've done it in the past when MenuItem or the repository were set in stone due to process or other restrictions. It still beats a conversion operator... Though a simple static helper method somewhere works as well of course.